# Why am I getting "Multiple applicable overloads" error on response.sendRedirect

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have an SS2 suitelet that is triggered from a button on a customer page,  does some processing, and redirects back to the originating page. Today it started giving a strange error

`failed due to: Multiple applicable overloads found for method name sendRedirect`

code is:

```
        context.response.sendRedirect({
            type: http.RedirectType.RECORD,
            identifier: record.Type.CUSTOMER,
            id: customerId,
            editMode: false,
            parameters: {
                custpage_success: 'T'
            }
        });
```

So this is in no fashion ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

In puzzling over this I saw that the script definition has a new field "Execute As Version" that read 2.1. I suspected this as the issue so went back and looked at my code:

The script type JSDOC comments were:

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType Suitelet
 */
```

which I've been doing since SS2 came out.

I adjusted this to

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.0
 *@NScriptType Suitelet
 */
```

and now "Execute as Version" says 2.0 and the redirect works again. I'm guessing someone was messing about in the account and decided to go to Setup -> Company -> General Preferences and set the default script level to 2.1

Comment: That's weird.  My understanding is that NetSuite controls which version 2.x will use and in the 2020.1 release notes, they state that 2.x will use 2.0 until 2021.1, at which time 2.x will refer to 2.1.

Comment: @MikeRobbins I guess they ended up putting that control at the account level.